# What is ScriptEditor2?

Tags: iphone, ios

It appears in my usage report in Settings as having 0.4KB of Documents and Data, but I've never installed anything by that name. It doesn't appear as an app on my home screen, and a Spotlight search turns up nothing. For that matter, a *Google* search turns up nothing. What the heck *is* it?

[image: Manage Storage screen, including an app called "ScriptEditor2"]

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: That's *my* question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.apple.ScriptEditor2` is the `CFBundleIdentifier` for **AppleScript Editor.app**.

The 0.4KB of iCloud data associated with [ScriptEditor2](http://www.iboostup.com/app/com.apple.scripteditor2) is likely to be a shared preference file created by AppleScript Editor on your Mac.

[image: AppleScript Editor icon]

Comment: Oh, I see, this is my *iCloud* usage, not my iPhone usage. That makes much more sense. :)